# How to position Popup over Header element?

Tags: html, css, popup, web-deployment, static-site

Here's the landing page: https://selfbrowser.github.io/self/

I want to show a popup automatically when someone lands of webpage. But only half on popup is window is visible. I'm confused how to positon that popup on webpage.

popup.css

```
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.popup{
    background-color: #0f72e5;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

index.html

```
        <div class="container">
            <!--POP UP FORM -->
             <div class="popup">
                <button id="close">&times;</button>
                <h2>Get Free Discounts, Offer Coupon in your inbox!</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos?
                </p>
                <form 
                method="POST" 
                action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyaUEskqvVM1oehXSA2ClQ7ZPeCOLwNluev9GpPFGKCTkFgPYjEC7jrf8Vr5leHoWC2HA/exec">
                    <input name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please fix & position the code at right place so that full popup window loads.

Comment: You should change the position to `fixed`

Comment: Simple as ... fixed